# Sequelize ORM - Update or delete on table "Users" violates foreign key constraint

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, foreign-keys, constraints

> Hi there,
>
> I am having an issue with my `deleteUser` function. The function should delete a user by their `UUID`, but when I run my test case, it fails with the following error message:

**Terminal output:**

```
✘ [fail]: deletetUser function should delete a user by uuid
    ℹ {
        error: 'update or delete on table "Users" violates foreign key constraint "Photos_user_id_fkey" on table "Photos"',
      }
  ─

  deletetUser function should delete a user by uuid
  tests/user/deleteUserTest.js:24

   23:     // Asserting that the status code of the response is 204
   24:     t.is(res.status, 204);                                  
   25:                                                             

  Difference (- actual, + expected):

  - 500
  + 204

  › tests/user/deleteUserTest.js:24:7

  ─

  1 test failed
```

> The error message suggests a foreign key constraint violation on the Photos table. Looking at the code, it seems that the User model has a hasMany association with the Photo model, where the foreign key is set to user_id, and the `onDelete` option is set to `'CASCADE'`. The Photo model also has a foreign key constraint that references the Users table.
>
> I have included the code for the `User` and `Photo` models as well as their migrations for reference.
>
> Can anyone help me understand what is causing the issue and how I can fix it? Thank you.

**User model:**

```
...

// Define a sequelize model for a User
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class User extends Model {
        /**
         * Helper method for defining associations.
         * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
         * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
         */
        static associate(models) {
            // define association here
            User.hasMany(models.Photo, {
                    foreignKey: 'user_id',
                    as: 'photos',
                    onDelete: 'CASCADE'
                }),
            User.hasMany(models.Caption, {
                    foreignKey: 'user_id',
                    as: 'captions',
                    onDelete: 'CASCADE'
                }),
            User.hasMany(models.Vote, {
                    foreignKey: 'user_id',
                    as: 'votes',
                    onDelete: 'CASCADE'
                })
        }
...
```

**User migration:**

```
'use strict';
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
    async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        await queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            uuid: {
                allowNull: false,
                unique: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: Sequelize.UUID,
                onDelete: 'CASCADE'
            },
...
```

**Photo model:**

```
'use strict';
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
    async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        await queryInterface.createTable('Photos', {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                unique: true,
                autoIncrement: true,
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            uuid: {
                allowNull: false,
                unique: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: Sequelize.UUID,
                onDelete: 'CASCADE'
            },
            url: {
                allowNull: false,
                unique: true,
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            user_id: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: Sequelize.UUID,
                references: {
                    model: 'Users',
                    key: 'uuid'
                },
                onDelete: 'CASCADE' // cascade deletes to associated photos when a user is deleted
            },
...
```

**Photo migration:**

```
'use strict';
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
    async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        await queryInterface.createTable('Photos', {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                unique: true,
                autoIncrement: true,
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            uuid: {
                allowNull: false,
                unique: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: Sequelize.UUID,
                onDelete: 'CASCADE'
            },
            url: {
                allowNull: false,
                unique: true,
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            user_id: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: Sequelize.UUID,
                references: {
                    model: 'Users',
                    key: 'uuid'
                },
                onDelete: 'CASCADE' // cascade deletes to associated photos when a user is deleted
            },
...
```

Comment: Check in DB that the foreign key `Photos_user_id_fkey` actually has ON DELETE CASCADE option

Comment: ````Foreign-key constraints:
    "Photos_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES "Users"(uuid)
````

Comment: conname | confrelid | confupdtype | confdeltype 
---------+-----------+-------------+-------------
(0 rows)

Comment: It looks like you don't have this option in the constraint thoiugh you have the correct option `onDelete: 'CASCADE'` for `user_id` field in the migration

Comment: I ran your migration and got `FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE`

Comment: Could it be that you changed the migration after you already applied it?

Comment: Thank you for all the valuable advice you provided me with. 
I was wrong about my assumption that deleting all values from the database tables would reset all the constraints. It was a mistake on my part to think that migrating and seeding tables after that was the solution. After reading your suggestions, dropping the database and recreating it, then migrating and seeding all the tables, was the correct approach. Thanks to your guidance, everything is now functioning as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252405/discussion-between-vetheve-and-anatoly).